# Comparing a time delta in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a variable which is `<type 'datetime.timedelta'>` and I would like to compare it against certain values.

Lets say d produces this `datetime.timedelta` value `0:00:01.782000`

I would like to compare it like this:

```
#if d is greater than 1 minute 
if d>1:00:
  print "elapsed time is greater than 1 minute"
```

I have tried converting `datetime.timedelta.strptime()` but that does seem to work. Is there an easier way to compare this value?

Comment: Note that `0:00:01.78200` is what a timedelta looks like when printed, but that's not a particularly useful format when debugging. Use `repr()` to show more accurate information. That way you might have guessed at the solution, as `repr(d)` would have shown `datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 782000)`

Answer (score 132):

You'll have to [create a new `timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) with the specified amount of time:

```
d > timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Or this slightly more complete script will help elaborate:

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

start = datetime.datetime.now()
sleep(3)
stop = datetime.datetime.now()

elapsed = stop - start

if elapsed > datetime.timedelta(minutes=1):
    print "Slept for > 1 minute"

if elapsed > datetime.timedelta(seconds=1):
    print "Slept for > 1 second"
```

Output:

`Slept for > 1 second`

Comment: Note if you're using Pandas there exists pandas.Timedelta with *capital T*...

Answer (score 21):

You just need to create `timedelta` object from scratch, comparison after that is trivial:

```
>>> a = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
>>> b = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1, seconds=1)
>>> a < b
True
>>> a > b
False
```

Answer (score 11):

You could say:

```
if elapsed.total_seconds() > 60:
    # elapsed time is greater than one minute
```

as opposed to instantiating another `timedelta`.

Comment: I have observed this approach to at least ignore `day=-1` and just pull the `seconds` field, and I suspect it always just pulls the `seconds` field instead of total elapsed seconds with the other fields added in.

Comment: yes the seconds parameter works for certain timedeltas, but it ignores days and milliseconds. If elapsed could be longer than hours or shorter than seconds, this does not work as expected. You should use `elapsed.total_seconds()` instead.

Answer (score 11):

```
if d.total_seconds() > 60:
  print("elapsed time is greater than 1 minute")
```

but it requires python 2.7+

Comment: total seconds docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds