# Different between two times with if function

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I will compare a dataset server time and the actual time. If the different greater than 1 minute, the script is continued. Else a waiting loop for example 10 sec. will start.

But I can't execute the if function. Thanks for your help!

That's the output:

```
last importtime: 2019-07-05 14:16:07
actual time:  2019-07-05 18:30:21
1 day, 4:14:14
```

Error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

#db-connection#
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",port="xx",user="xx",passwd="xxx",database="traiding")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("select max(imported) from import_log")

data_sql=mycursor.fetchall()

#last import from database'
data=pd.DataFrame(data_sql, columns=['date'])


#close connection#
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()


#last import date#
lastimported=datetime.strftime(data_sql[0][0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("last importtime:",lastimported)

#lastimport=datetime.strptime(lastimported, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


current_time=datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print ("actual time: ", current_time)


s1 = lastimported
s2 = current_time
FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
print (tdelta)

min_time=datetime.strptime('00:01:00', "%H:%M:%S")

if tdelta > min_time :
    print (">0") # Do Something
else:
    print ("else") # Waiting loop, for example 10sec
```

Comment: `'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.datetime'` the error tells you that you're not trying to get the difference between two times, you're trying to compare a time-difference with an actual datetime.

Comment: Why are you converting datetime objects to strings and then back to datetime objects again? `current_time=datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`, to then do `datetime.strptime(s2, FMT)` where `s2` is `current_time` which was _already_ a datetime object if you hadn't called `strftime` at the end

Comment: In any case, I think the only thing that's throwing me here is the hard-coded value for `s1`. If you could clarify why that is being used then I kinda get what you're trying to do and will try answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing a time delta in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591845/comparing-a-time-delta-in-python)

Comment: @Akaisteph7 you answer and flag as a dupe within less than 1 minute?

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake. I'm tested a lot of possibilities. The correct s1 = lastimported. I've changed in the code above.

Comment: @roganjosh: When I used strptime, i can't calculate the different between s1 and s2. I don't no why, but does't work! It works only with strftime   and than back to strptime ...

Comment: That's an XY problem. You're misdiagnosing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare the timedelta object to another timedelta object.

```
import datetime as dt

#... Your code

if tdelta > dt.timedelta(minutes=1):
    print (">0") # Do Something
else:
    print ("else") # Waiting loop, for example 10sec
```

Comment: It is a part of a bigger script. This part will control the import part to get data from a api. Like a cronjob with adjustable set of parameters. 

I will look on my last import timestamp (s1) and compare this with the actual time (s2). If the different greater than 1 minute, than the script will be start. 

Do you understand that?

Comment: @roganjosh What is the issue with this code? I am not sure I understand how this does not solve exactly what you are asking for