# discord.py How can I send a message if difference between the time of message and current time is above time I specified?

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py, python-datetime

```
timestamp = f'{message.created_at}'
msg_time = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
now_time = datetime.now()
diff = now_time - msg_time


print('msg_time:', msg_time)
print('now_time:', now_time)
print('diff    :', diff)
```

output :

```
msg_time: 2022-07-22 06:02:12.934000
now_time: 2022-07-23 01:53:52.375086
diff    : 19:51:39.441086
```

If diff is greater than the time I specify, I want it to send a message to the channel like this:

```
if diff > 00:01:00.000000:
  title2 = "test."
  embed2 = discord.Embed(title=title2, color=0xf1c40f)
  msg = await channels.send(embed=embed2)
```

I made it here so that if it's longer than 1 minute, it can be sent, but I don't know exactly, so it doesn't work, how can I do it?

Comment: What if you used timedelta.total_seconds()? Then, if your total_seconds exceeded some value, then you could trigger your response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing a time delta in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591845/comparing-a-time-delta-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using timedelta.total_seconds()

```
diff = diff.total_seconds()
```

This will convert the time difference into an integer representing the time in seconds. You can use that value much easier.

> References:
>
> https://pythontic.com/datetime/timedelta/total_seconds
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-timedelta-total_seconds-method-with-example/