# Comparing Datetimes but Pycharm warning says should be timedelta object

Tags: python, datetime, pycharm

I appreciate this has been asked many times e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591845/comparing-a-time-delta-in-python) so I'm interested to check if this is an error within PyCharm.   I have two datetime objects: now() and lastupdated, plus an integer called update_period.   I want to know if the update period has expired.

```
soonest_update = last_updated + timedelta(seconds=update_period)
now = datetime.now()

print(type(soonest_update), type(now))

if soonest_update > now:
    # and so on.
```

The code works and produces correct answers but Pycharm says that *now* should be a time delta object.  The actual error message is *Expected type 'timedelta', got 'datetime' instead*

```
print(type(soonest_update), type(now))
```

outputs *<class 'datetime.datetime'> <class 'datetime.datetime'>*

If I take the accepted solution from the link above

```
print(type(res), type(res2))
```

also outputs *<class 'datetime.datetime'> <class 'datetime.datetime'>* but there is no error message or warning.

Is this just an incorrect warning within PyCharm?

Comment: Can you please show the exact message?

Comment: Not easily because its one of those pop-up / hover-over messages.  I've added a copy and paste of the main bit.

Comment: "*Is this just an incorrect warning within PyCharm?*" - I would say yes. You can compare datetime with datetime and timedelta with timedelta, but datetime vs. timedelta makes no sense to me. That's apples and pears.

Comment: Thank you @FObersteiner.   It didn't make any sense to me especially with the type reporting as identical.

Comment: maybe you can report a bug somewhere; I'm not using PyCharm so I can't be more specific. But this warning is definitely misleading.